# Is it reasonable to calculate $P(X_1 = X_2)$ given that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are continuous random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

To be specific, suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent exponential random variables with parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$; what is $P(X_1 = X_2)$?

According to section 5.2.3 of the book "Introduction to Probability Models" by Sheldon M.Ross (the 10th edition), $P(X_1 < X_2) = \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$. Symmetrically, $P(X_1 > X_2) = \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$.

$$P(X_1 < X_2) = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X_1 < X_2 \mid X_1 = x) \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x}dx \\ = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(x < X_2) \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x}dx \\ = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda_2 x} \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x}dx \\ = \int_{0}^{\infty} \lambda_1 e^{-(\lambda_1  + \lambda_2) x}dx = \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}.$$

**My Problems:**

1. Can I now conclude that $P(X_1 = X_2) = 1 - P(X_1 < X_2) - P(X_1 > X_2) = 0$?
2. I am confused about the argument because of the fact that the probability that a continuous random variable will take on any *particular* value is zero. Is it reasonable to calculate the probability that the two variables *simultaneously* take on the same particular value?
3. If so, how to calculate $P(X_1 = X_2)$ directly, in the same way used in the calculation of $P(X_1 < X_2)$? Furthermore, can this calculation be applied to all continuous random variables?

Comment: Your confusion is more basic: given any continous random variable (say, $X$ exponential) is $P(X=x)=0$?

Comment: @leonbloy Isn't it? As I understand it, the claim that `the probability that a continuous random variable will take on any particular value is zero` is exactly about this. Do I miss or misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be confusing to think of an event such as $\{X_1=X_2\}$, since both sides are random; perhaps it will be easier to think about it a little differently.

Instead of considering the event that $X_1=X_2$, let's consider the (clearly equivalent) event that $X_1-X_2=0$.  Note that $X_1-X_2$ is just another random variable -- and, in particular, since $X_1$ and $X_2$ both have densities, *and are independent*, it is not hard to show that $X_1-X_2$ also has a density.

We can compute that density, $f_{X_1-X_2}$, explicitly by considering cases:

If $x\geq0$, then
$$
f_{X_1-X_2}(x)=\int_x^{\infty}f_{X_1}(t)\cdot f_{X_2}(t-x)\,dt=\frac{\lambda_1\lambda_2e^{-\lambda_1x}}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2},
$$
while for $x<0$ we have
$$
f_{X_1-X_2}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_{X_1}(x-t)\cdot f_{X_2}(-t)\,dt=\frac{\lambda_1\lambda_2e^{\lambda_2x}}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}.
$$

where $f_{X_1}$ and $f_{X_2}$ are the densities for $X_1$ and $X_2$, respectively.

But, since $X_1-X_2$ has a density, it is a continuous random variable -- and so the probability that it takes any particular value is $0$.

Comment: I notice that before computing the density $f_{X_1 - X_2}$, you first claim that it *exists*. Could you please give some explanations? As a non-mathematical student, I often tend to forget and misunderstand such rigorous things.

Comment: If you want to do that, it can be done by considering CDF's; you can show that if $A$ and $B$ are independent random variables (think $X_1$ and $-X_2$) then $C=A+B$ has CDF $F_C(z)=\mathbb{E}[F_A(z-B)]$. (The thought process is that $A+B\leq z$ if and only if $A\leq z-B$.) You could compute this, then show that it is nicely differentiable... and voila.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes.
2. Yes.
3. Your confusion appears to be the following.  If $X_1,X_2$ are continuously distributed random variables then $X_1-X_2$ may or may not be continuously distributed.  If $X_1-X_2$ is continuously distributed then $\Pr(X_1=X_2)=0$.  If it is not continuously distributed then it can be anything.  For instance, suppose that $X_1$ has a $N(0,1)$ distribution, $Z$ has a Bernoulli (0/1) distribution with $p=0.5$ and $X_2=X_1+Z$.  Then $X_1,X_2$ have continuous distributions but $\Pr(X_1=X_2)=0.5$.

Comment: Interesting points and nice example! Never thought that the difference of two continuous random variables could be discrete; it is quite clear after your explanation. If I want to calculate $P(X_1 = X_2)$ directly, how should I go further with $P(X_1 = X_2) = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X_1 = X_2 \mid X_1 = x) \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X_2 = x) \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x}dx$?
Could I substitute in $P(X_2 = x) = 0$ directly? Is this mathematically rigorous?

Comment: The natural thing to do would be to derive the distribution function of $Z=X_1-X_2$, i.e. $$\Pr(Z\leq z)=\int_0^z \Pr(X_1\leq z-x) f_{X_2}(x) dx$$ and then check if there is a jump at $z=0$.  In your case there isn't.

Comment: What would a jump at $z = 0$ imply?

Comment: That there is a mass point at zero.  The jump is $\Pr(Z=0)$.